# Detecting if folder exists and renaming by pattern

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Me again with another command-line script question :)

I made a helper script that looks like this

```
echo 'target.bak -> target.old_bak'
mv target.bak target.old_bak
echo 'target -> target.bak'
mv target target.bak
echo 'git clone:target -> target'
git clone ssh://Shark@mcs15:29418/our-trunk-target target
cd target
echo 'Managing hooks...'
scp -p -P 29418 Shark@mcs15:/hooks/commit-msg .git/hooks/
echo '... done. Enjoy the new clone while it lasts...'
```

This is pretty basic but it gets my point across - it keeps the last two clones and makes a new one, I need to retain my latest clone in the `target` folder because i symlinked my source folder in my eclipse project to point there :D

I would like to make an improvement to this script - instead of renaming `target.bak -> target.old_bak` and `target -> target.bak` I would like the following to happen:

```
if bakN exists then rename bakN -> bak(N+1)
rename recursivelly bak(N-1) -> bakN
rename target to target.bak
clone new repo into target
```

So in case I had gone through 6 clones and I'm cloning for the seventh time I'd like this to happen:

```
target.bak4 -> target.bak5
target.bak3 -> target.bak4
target.bak2 -> target.bak3
target.bak1 -> target.bak2
target.bak0 -> target.bak1
target      -> target.bak0
Cloning into 'target'...
```

This community helped me immensely with my previous mass-diffing question so I hope you will be helpful enough to provide me with a decent way to do this one as well :)

EDIT:

The finalized script looks like this, thanks Wolfie for your major contributions.

```
#!/bin/bash
MYUSER="Shark"
TRUNK_FOLDER="target-on-trunk"
TARGET_FOLDER="target"

if [ -n "`ls -1d -v ${TARGET_FOLDER}.bak?`" ]; then
    echo "Pushing back numbered backups..."
    MAXBCK=`ls -1d ${TARGET_FOLDER}.bak* 2>/dev/null | egrep -o "[0-9]+$" | sort -n | tail -n1`
    if [ "$MAXBCK" != "" ]; then
        for (( c=$MAXBCK; c>=0; c-- ))
            do
                mv -v ${TARGET_FOLDER}.bak$c ${TARGET_FOLDER}.bak$(($c+1))
        done
    fi
fi

if [ -e "$TARGET_FOLDER.bak" ]; then
        mv -v ${TARGET_FOLDER}.bak ${TARGET_FOLDER}.bak0
fi

if [ -e "$TARGET_FOLDER" ]; then
        mv -v ${TARGET_FOLDER} ${TARGET_FOLDER}.bak
fi

echo "git clone: ${TRUNK_FOLDER} -> ${TARGET_FOLDER}"
git clone ssh://${MYUSER}@mcs15:29418/${TRUNK_FOLDER} ${TARGET_FOLDER}
cd ${TARGET_FOLDER}
echo 'Managing hooks...'
scp -p -P 29418 ${MYUSER}@mcs15:/hooks/commit-msg .git/hooks/
echo '... done. Enjoy the new clone while it lasts...'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could help you:

For this files:

```
target.bak4 -> target.bak5
target.bak3 -> target.bak4
target.bak2 -> target.bak3
target.bak1 -> target.bak2
target.bak0 -> target.bak1
```

You can do this:

`ls -1 target.bak* | awk '{print "mv "$0" "substr($0,0,length)substr($0,length,1)+1}' | sh`

For `target      -> target.bak0` just do `cp target target.bak`

**Update:**

I tested this command and works only from 0 -> 19 backup, than the renaming fails... but for what you need is OK :)

**Update #2:**

Script version:

```
if [ $# != 1 ]; then
        echo 'Usage: $0 target'
        exit
fi
if [ `ls -1 $1* 2>/dev/null | grep -c $1` -lt 1 ]; then
        echo "No file found"
        exit
fi

MAXBCK=`ls -1 $1.bak* 2>/dev/null | egrep -o "[0-9]+$" | sort -n | tail -n1`

if [ "$MAXBCK" != "" ]; then
        for (( c=$MAXBCK; c>=0; c-- ))
        do
        #       echo $c $(($c+1))
                mv $1.bak$c $1.bak$(($c+1))
        done
fi

cp $1 $1.bak0
```

Example:

```
wolfy@wolfy-ubuntu:~/tmp$ ll
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wolfy wolfy 402 May 27 14:43 fresh_clone.sh*
-rw-r--r-- 1 wolfy wolfy   0 May 27 14:10 test
wolfy@wolfy-ubuntu:~/tmp$ ./fresh_clone.sh test
wolfy@wolfy-ubuntu:~/tmp$ ll
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wolfy wolfy 402 May 27 14:43 fresh_clone.sh*
-rw-r--r-- 1 wolfy wolfy   0 May 27 14:10 test
-rw-r--r-- 1 wolfy wolfy   0 May 27 14:44 test.bak0
wolfy@wolfy-ubuntu:~/tmp$ ./fresh_clone.sh test
wolfy@wolfy-ubuntu:~/tmp$ ll
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wolfy wolfy 402 May 27 14:43 fresh_clone.sh*
-rw-r--r-- 1 wolfy wolfy   0 May 27 14:10 test
-rw-r--r-- 1 wolfy wolfy   0 May 27 14:44 test.bak0
-rw-r--r-- 1 wolfy wolfy   0 May 27 14:44 test.bak1
wolfy@wolfy-ubuntu:~/tmp$ ./fresh_clone.sh test
wolfy@wolfy-ubuntu:~/tmp$ ll
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wolfy wolfy 402 May 27 14:43 fresh_clone.sh*
-rw-r--r-- 1 wolfy wolfy   0 May 27 14:10 test
-rw-r--r-- 1 wolfy wolfy   0 May 27 14:44 test.bak0
-rw-r--r-- 1 wolfy wolfy   0 May 27 14:44 test.bak1
-rw-r--r-- 1 wolfy wolfy   0 May 27 14:44 test.bak2
```

Try with this... but keep in mind that this is only a sample code, for "production" you should add some check before running this :)

This version works with N bak files... not only 19 ;)

Comment: how hard would it be to replace `target` with a $1 sortof argument? perhaps making it so that invoking it as `fresh_clone.sh target` would work too?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: ups, someting is wrong here... I will try to correct this :)

Comment: I found out a few quirks which I'm ironing out as well. I will accept this as an answer and post my final version later :)

Now I'm trying to make it somewhat more customizable, trying to define the user at the start.

Comment: I added a script... again... this version is different from my firs command...

Comment: The new one doesn't work for me, it crashes the terminal when I use it to pull in the first clone.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8955/discussion-between-wolfy-and-shark)

Answer (score 2):

I normally advise against using `ls` in a program ([rationale here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)) but this seems straightforward, so:

```
touch target.bak{0..10}   # for testing

base=target
bak="${base}.bak"
command ls -vr "$bak"* | while IFS= read -r file; do
    n=${file#$bak}
    echo mv "$bak$n" "$bak$((n+1))"
done
echo mv "$base" "${bak}0"
```

```
mv target.bak10 target.bak11
mv target.bak9 target.bak10
mv target.bak8 target.bak9
mv target.bak7 target.bak8
mv target.bak6 target.bak7
mv target.bak5 target.bak6
mv target.bak4 target.bak5
mv target.bak3 target.bak4
mv target.bak2 target.bak3
mv target.bak1 target.bak2
mv target.bak0 target.bak1
mv target target.bak0
```

Notes:

- use `command` to avoid any aliases or functions for `ls`
- use ls's `-v` option to ensure files are sorted "numerically"

  - i.e., so "target.bak10" follows "target.bak9", not "target.bak1"